# Code not appearing in code blocks

Tags: support

I believe this is a bug, but I'm not 100% sure.

I added my code to the editor, and indented four spaces, but the code still doesn't show in a code block.

This is what it looks like in edit:
[image: edit]
This is what it looks like on the front-end.
[image: front-end]

What should I do?

Comment: I don't think you can have code blocks within numbered lists. At least I tried to do this before, and also failed.

Comment: Highlight the text and click the bracket in the editor topbar.

Comment: @SantaClaus, did that, still doesn't work.

Comment: @RetoKoradi I hit enter like 5 times before to see if it would change and it still didn't show up properly.

Comment: Have you tried to hit enter 5 times before also?

Comment: Try squeezing a '.' or any sort of character between the list and code placed 0 spaces in (ie no indent) with a blank line before and after it.

Comment: @SantaClaus, meant to say before. Edited

Comment: @indivisible putting a period between the list and code worked, but I do still think this is a bug.

Comment: You can also indent it 8 spaces but then its in line with the numbered list text.

Comment: @SantaClaus, I indented 8 spaces and it looks better now. Should I close this, or what now?

Comment: @SantaClaus: You're a genius! ;) Indenting 8 spaces does exactly what I was trying to do in the past. I looked in the advanced help for the edit box again, and don't see that documented.

Comment: Ok, it is documented. Under "Advanced Lists: Nesting", there's an expandable section that is collapsed by default. It's at the bottom of that section, under "Preformatted text in a list item".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Numbered lists change the normal behavior of code blocks.  You can do one of the following:

Indent with 8 spaces (This will indent it with the numbered list):

1. Stuff...

   ```
   <html></html>
   ```

You can also put a comment `<!-- -->` before the code block and indent with four spaces for it to not be indented with the numbered list:

1. Stuff...

```
<html></html>
```

Answer (score 5):

Indent your code by 8 spaces, instead of the usual 4.