# Code not rendered properly

Tags: bug, code-formatting, markdown-rendering

I have put a bounty on a question a few days ago. I then came across a rendering problem. As you can see here, the code is not rendered properly, but is written properly as markdown:

[image: Wrong rendered code.]

I have tried editing it myself, but it still doesn't seem to render correctly. I even tried viewing it in Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox (across two computers), and on my mobile phone. None of them seems to render the code properly.

[See it here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34203654/5305938)

**Note:** It seems to me like it's only the second answer's code which is rendered incorrectly.

Comment: The list was breaking it. You might notice the answer has been edited, and if you check the markdown you'll see how. This comes up plenty because there's nothing to indicate it's the list causing the issue.

Comment: [This answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265767/2607247) should explain well enough how code interacts with lists.

Comment: *It seems to me like it's only the second answer's code which is rendered incorrectly.* - The first line of code in the first answer is formatted incorrectly too, though they don't have a list in their answer.

Comment: @BSMP The first line of the first answer isn't written correctly.

Comment: @JacquesMarais - I  know.

Comment: I fixed the first answer by creating the pre and code tags myself so I could mix that bold in that obviously was intended by the OP. If you use markdown for code formatting you cannot use any other markdown or html tags inside that block.